# A Simple Math Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

So my last math puzzle was too easy apparently, and this one might be too. Either way, the rules are the same.

- No rotation.
- No duplication.
- No combination.
- No rounding.
- No computers.

---

### **Good luck to all of you!**

---

You are given the following set of numbers: $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9$. Inject these numbers into the following equation to create a true statement.

$$\frac{21a + \frac{5b}{c}}{d} + e = f$$

---

### **Note**

It was pointed out in the chat that I made a typo. I've corrected the number set; and I apologize to everyone for that mistake.

Comment: Oh boy, 720 possible combinations to choose from... Where to start.....

Comment: Is there a **single** solution?

Comment: There is only one solution.

Comment: You sure there is a solution to this?

Comment: Well I imagine it was developed in reverse, so probably

Comment: This is going to take a while

Comment: I am positive there is a solution to this.

Comment: After trying to solve this, I gave up and made a Python script to try every possible combination. I haven't been able to find an answer that doesn't require rounding. I'll check again in case I made a mistake, but it's either that or this requires some lateral thinking.

Comment: @Racso Same here. My script found no true combinations of the numbers.

Comment: @Rasco It says no computer

Comment: @PotatoLatte I know. As I said, "I gave up", so I wasn't going to post the answer in case I found one.

Comment: In that case, if there is no solution, maybe the "lateral thinking" tag should be added? (Although maybe then it would give it away...)

Comment: Maybe there's some lateral thinking then? Something besides rounding, duplicating, combining, or rotating?

Comment: For those who give up and want the answer; feel free to join me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83491/perpetual-riddles) for the answer. If you enter the chat and post the answer afterwards, your answer will not be accepted.

Comment: Update from the chat: the 4 in the set should be a 6 instead.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{21a + \frac{5b}{c}}{d} + e = f$$ is true when

> a = 2
>
>  b = 3
>
>  c = 5
>
>  d = 9
>
>  e = 1
>
>  f = 6

Comment: HAHA That was an awesome loop hole; however, it isn't the correct answer. I've updated the post as I made a typo. That should help lol

Comment: @Perp Changed now that the 4 is a 6

Answer (score 2):

Also not really an answer, but this is the closest I've gotten

> $\frac{21*1 + \frac{5*4}{3}}{9} + 2 = 5\tfrac{2}{27}$ which is only off by $\frac{2}{27}$. So far that's the smallest margin of error that I could find. However rounding isn't allowed so...

EDIT: Actual answer:

> $\frac{21*2 + \frac{5*3}{5}}{9} + 1 = 6$

Comment: The answer is similar to this. :)

Comment: @Perp Is mine correct?

Comment: Dang it! Too slow again! :P

Comment: d=9 is an overlap. also f=6 is kinda close to f = 5 and 2/27...

Comment: He found $d$ and $f$ was close but no rounding allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some facts I have found to help the community:

> C != 4,9

Comment: That is a true statement. :)